# Creating a new keyboard button for iPhone - Bug in InputAccessoryView and InputView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uitextview

I create a 2 `UITextView` in my program. They will have to do this:

- TextView1 - Will have a new InputView
- TextView2 - Will be a normal numeric keyboard with a new button

Because the numeric keyboard of iPhone have a empty button in left of zero. So, I can put a UIView there to simulate a new keyboard. So, I created a UIView with a UIToolbar and this button and set in TextView with a simple

```
[textView setInputAccessoryView:myView];
```

To catch a click inside this view is a little more complex. I have to subclass the `principalClassName` in main.m

```
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, MyPrincialClass ,MyDelegateClass);
```

Then create this class with

```
@interface MyPrincialClass : UIApplication
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)anEvent;
@end
@implementation MyPrincialClass
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super sendEvent:event];
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = touches.anyObject;
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"click" object:(id)touch];
}
@end
```

Now is only listen this Notification and check if this click is in correct area.

Because I have a UINavegationBar, I have to go to "Next" and "Previous" TextView. OK, this is only run

```
[textView1 resignFirstResponder];
[textView2 becomeFirstResponder];
```

If all textView have the same inputView (the keyboard) than the button work normaly. But... Because one of this textView have another inputView, than my problem start.

If I first click in a normal UITextView  with a button, than the button is show correct like this. The red square is above the keyboard, so it work.

[image: work fine]

If the first click is in the UITextView with a customized inputView, the button is show correct again

[image: I will not use this way, but work]

but now, If navegate with the tool bar (with is a simple `resignFirstResponder` and `becomeFirstResponder`) the button will be show under the keyboard

[image: Fail...]
[image: Fail again...]

In resume... All the problem in only because I use a custom inputview. If I only use the keyboard, I will not have any problem.

To solve this, is only put the UIView of custom button above the keyboard. I try to get the main UIWindows and send the message:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow bringSubviewToFront:myview];
```

But not work. Any idea to solve this bug??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it. The idea was find the UIView of keyboard and add the button like a subview. This was the codes:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow {
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(UIView* potentialKeyboard in tempWindow.subviews) {
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[potentialKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES) {
                keyboard = potentialKeyboard;
            } else {
                if([[potentialKeyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES) {
                    keyboard = potentialKeyboard;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    [keyboard addSubview:key];
    [keyboard bringSubviewToFront:key];
}
```

Comment: Ummm... not sure, but I have a strong  feeling that if you submit this to the app store you may get rejected. Don;t think your supposed to play with their internal view structure like that. What is it you want to achieve with this, do you just need one more button, and what is it for?

Comment: This is quite bad. __WHY__ the if-statement _inside_ the for-loop? And this will crash when no keyboard is found.

Comment: @Joost the if is because the version above 3.2 changed the name of object that have the keyboard. And this have 2 name. Yes, if in future Apple change the name, I will have troubles... Thanks, I will fix it

Comment: @GeorgeGreen it because I have to enter X, because the user account have base 11, like ISBN that need X like a check digit.

Comment: @Rodrigo that wasn't the `if` I was referring to, I mean the `UIDevice systemVersion` check. This can, and should, be done outside of the for-loop.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. It's only a small error. It check more times than it need.

Answer (score 0):

I Hope i understand you correctly, and i would suggest you to manage Z Position of the button. So that It can appear above all the component. For easy doing i suggest you the following open source,[Manage Z Order of Views](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/open-source/ios-open-source-uiview-category-to-manage-z-order-of-views.html).
Hope this will help you, if not please let me know .

Cheers,
Arun.